# Reading timestamps from a file and convert to ms

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I'm trying to write a program in Python that will:

- take a .csv file as input
- read the timestamps in the second row
- print the difference in time between each timestamp as ms

The code works when I write the timestamps in a variable, but nothing happens when I try to use a file as input. The program runs, but nothing is printed to the console.

This is how the code looks:

```
import csv
import datetime
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
toopen = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text file","*.txt")])

with open(toopen, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        code = row[0]
        times = row[1].split()
        times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for x in times]
        for i in range(len(times) - 1):
            delta = times[i + 1] - times[i]
            print ((delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds) * 1000 + delta.microseconds / 1000)
```

Here's a sample of how my input file looks.

```
input23 13:13:05.674430
input47 13:13:06.623822
input52 13:13:07.573215
input66 13:13:08.522607
```

Any help is appreciated because I'm really stuck here!
Thanks

Comment: If nothing is printed, then you opened an empty file perhaps.

Comment: I rechecked and the file is, sadly, not the problem.

Comment: Perhaps `row[1]` only has *one* timestamp in it, no whitespace? Without sample input this is impossible to tell. Your code looks otherwise correct.

Comment: Why are you opening the file as binary?

Comment: Added a sample of my input file. I tried opening the file without binary, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you splitting what `row[1]` returns? That's just one timestamp and you're making a list of **one** item from it.

Then, in the list comprehension, you're iterating over that list with **one** timestamp and make a list of **one** `datetime` instance from it.

Note that `len(times)` at that point is 1. So when doing `for i in range(len(times) - 1)`, you're effectively iterating over `range(0)`, which is an empty list.

What you actually want is to have the second for loop outside of the first. Or even better, replace the whole first `for row in reader:` loop with a simpler list comprehension, like so:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for _, timestamp in reader]

for i in range(len(times) - 1):
    delta = times[i + 1] - times[i]
    print ((delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds) * 1000 + delta.microseconds / 1000)
```

If you want to, you can improve the remaining `for` loop by replacing `range()` and the indexing by iterating over pairs of a `datetime` instance and its successor by `zip()`ing up the list with a version of itself shifted by one place, which is arguably a wee bit more readable and pythonic:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for _, timestamp in reader]

for time1, time2 in zip(times, times[1:]):
    delta = time2 - time1
    print ((delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds) * 1000 + delta.microseconds / 1000)
```

As J.F. Sebastian notes, you can get the total number of milliseconds a lot easier from the `timedelta` by using `total_seconds()` instead of combining all 3 components manually. Since that already returns a result with microsecond resolution (it's a float), you just need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds. If you want or don't mind the fractional part, you're done, otherwise you need to `round()` and/or convert to `int()`:

```
    print(delta.total_seconds() * 1000)
```

or

```
    print(int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000))
```

Comment: you could use `1000 * delta.total_seconds()` to get milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied that line from the question and didn't bother examining it, since it's not related to the problem. But you're of course correct, that's another part that can be improved.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks for the suggestion, edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! Your explanation pointed out well what was wrong with my code when I couldn't see the error. Thanks!